# Why is a SQL JOIN query giving results from the wrong table?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm running the following SQL query in Hive:

```
select i.dt,c.name,count(*) 
from table_i i 
join table_c c on i.ai = c.ai 
where i.dt between '20210920' and '20210925' 
and i.id = '45632' 
group by i.dt,c.name;
```

The result I want should have the count(*) from table_i with i.dt and c.name.

i.dt      c.name        count(*) table_i
20210920  denver                25
20210920  san francisco         30
20210921  denver                35
20210921  san francisco         45

20210921
...
Instead, I seem to be getting the count from table_c, with i.dt and c.name.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Your getting the “count of table c” because your join type is restricting your result set to only those that find a match in table c. When using ‘join’ by itself, your result set cannot exceed the number of rows in table c.

Comment: May be replace join with left join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.dt, c.name, count(*) 
from table_i 
INNER JOIN table_c 
ON i.ai = c.ai 
WHERE (i.dt  BETWEEN 20210920 AND 20210925) AND (i.id = 45632) 
GROUP BY i.dt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).